# MongoDB Connection Issues

Tags: replication, mongodb-3.0, connection-pooling

We have a MEAN application with a 3-member MongoDB replica set. Somehow the total connection count keeps increasing until the primary is not able to take any new connections and goes down, making the application painfully slow. I have set the ulimit to 30000 and restarted the MongoDB and in no time it got 28000+ connection opened and primary went down.

Any idea why this may be happening? Most of the connections are between the different ports on primary with port 27017 on primary (for instance,  primary_server:45002 to primary_server:27017).

Comment: Please post MongoDB driver and server version too. Also look at MongoDB log to find out any problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have right UNIX ulimit Settings.You can see also: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/
2. Use top command to check if the performance bottleneck is CPU overload.Check the mongodb log file if there is any slow query,and you can use MTools to analyse it.Then you need optimize the slow query.
3. Use free command to check if not enough physical memory is available.If MongoDB has too many connections,you need to check Stack settings.every connection is a thread,need a Stack,Stack settings usually is too large by default in Linux:
   `shell> ulimit -a | grep stack`
   You can see the real used Stack size,like this:
   `shell> cat /proc/$(pidof mongod)/limits | grep stack | awk -F 'size' '{print int($NF)/1024}'`
   The total mem consumed by connections is so large,I suggest you set it smaller,such as 1024:
   `shell> ulimit -s 1024`

Comment: There is nothing going on the server as top shows a load average of 0.02 and there is no query running. Setting up the ulimit is also not helping as whatever limit you set, it will open that many connection(mostly from primary to primary) and take the primary down.

Comment: we are using mongodb 3.2 along with mongoose 4.03 and on one of the secondary server, netstat | grep 27017 | wc -l gives
13774 and this number is keep increasing by 8-10 every second(same is the number in the mongo log on primary server). I changed the sync target also, but still nothing changed and CPU load alos keep increasing with top output as .66 however RAM usgae doesnt increase at all

Comment: Perhaps you could see about MongoDB Connection Pooling: http://blog.mlab.com/2013/11/deep-dive-into-connection-pooling/

Comment: But RAM usage is not high, it remains at 3 GB for most of the time(event when connection count shows 10000+ or 25000+)  and it's always only one secondary that has that many connections to the primary while the other secondary will have around 300 connections at max.

Comment: Can this be due to isMaster() being run by the mongoose client? How can I check what these connections are doing?

Comment: I see a lot of these kind of queries running        query: { ismaster: true }  ntoreturn: -1 ntoskip: 0
10.117.241.104:27017  <<--  10.117.241.104:38837   480 bytes  id:16f386 1504134 - 1602
        reply n:1 cursorId: 0                                                                            on primary. This is causing a connection bottleneck.How can I handle this

Comment: If only one secondary has many connections,you can know where they are from by mongostat.From the output values of insert/query/update/delete you can know whether the operation requests are from primary for replication which had a star before the number.you can know roughly which kind of operation the are from.Then use mongo shell command db.currentOp(),you can know current operations detailly.Then you use MongoDB Profiler logs all operations to database by command db.setProfilingLevel(2).Then db.system.profile.find() can find the details.

Comment: Nothng is running on the server Mongostat
                      
 PRIMARY.COM     *0    *0     *0     *0       0    76|0     0.3    0.6       0  7.7G 981.0M   0|0   0|0    5k    52k 6169 prod  PRI 2016-03-22T12:05:40+05:30
SECONDARY1.COM     *0    *0     *0     *0       0    16|0     0.0    0.2       0  1.0G  95.0M   0|0   0|0    1k    25k   97 prod  SEC 2016-03-22T12:05:40+05:30
SECONDARY2.COM     *0    *0     *0     *0       0    19|0     0.1    1.7       0  1.6G 515.0M   0|0   0|0    1k    27k  270 prod  SEC 2016-03-22T12:05:40+05:30

Comment: Please run the commands on the high connection mongodb server when the connections are large.

Comment: I did so, the output is similar even when the connection count is 28000+

Comment: To check mongod.log for details.

Comment: Mongo Log(Primary)
2016-03-22T14:38:13.360+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 10.67.91.213:33599 #101677 (17644 connections now open)
2016-03-22T14:38:13.360+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 10.67.91.213:33600 #101678 (17645 connections now open)

Mongo Log(Secondary)
Nothing related to this
netstat | grep 27017 | wc -l
24690
(Secondary that keeps making connection)

Comment: $ tail -f ./mongod.log
To trace current log info.

Comment: In mongo logs we see first a new connection is established and then Successfully authenticated as principal **username** on **dbname**                       2016-03-23T11:50:32.557+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 10.67.91.213:59481 #129786 (8246 connections now open)
2016-03-23T11:50:32.575+0530 I ACCESS   [conn129779] Successfully authenticated as principal ekaushal on eKaushal

Comment: It sounds like there is a bug in your code (likely) or mongoose (less likely) that either creates more connections than it closes or never closes connections in the first place.